# Add FreeBase API fails in Eclipse Juno

Tags: google-app-engine, freebase

I have a new Google App Engine project (1.7.3) and want to add the FreeBase API through the GPE tooling --> Add Google APIs.

I have an older project where I succesfully downloaded the API which resulted in this classpath entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.MANAGED_API_CONTAINER/freebase-v1r10lv1.7.2-beta"/>
```

The .log of eclipse tells me this:

```
MESSAGE IO error while downloading http://api-directory.googleapis.com/5935/download-apiary/freebase/v1?lang=java&dependencies=1
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://api-directory.googleapis.com/5935/download-apiary/freebase/v1?lang=java&dependencies=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.jobs.DownloadRunnable.run(DownloadRunnable.java:81)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.platform.ManagedApiInstallJob.run(ManagedApiInstallJob.java:190)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.ui.ApiImportWizard$2.execute(ApiImportWizard.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation$1.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:106)
```

When I try to access the URL with a browser a also get a 502 error.

I tried adding another API, the books API, and that went fine, but I want to use the FreeBase API.
I am getting the error for both the preferred and sandbox options that are available in the API list.

Comment: I copied the .google_apis from the existing (working) project to my new project and added the classpath entry mentioned above.

Comment: This helps me to continu, but still the GPE route should work, right ?